# How to change the default Mail account in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, mail.app

This Question is the same as this one : [How to change the default Mail account in Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61882/how-to-change-the-default-mail-account-in-mountain-lion)

> I have 2 mail accounts configured. When composing a new message, it will default to the account for the currently selected mailbox, which is fine. However, when no particular mailbox is selected (when viewing the combined Inbox for example), it will default to the first listed mail account.
>
> How can I change the default mail account when no particular mailbox is active? IIRC, you used to be able to drag them into order, but this no longer seems to work.
>
> I am aware that you can specify a default mail account for all new messages, but I'd like to preserve the behavior where it will default to the account of the currently active mailbox, if one is active.

The answer doesn't work anymore on El Capitan.
When no particular mailbox is active the default account is the first in the alphabetical order of the emails address, not names, which is a bit difficult to modify !

Comment: not an answer, I was just pushing some buttons to confirm your theories... You can still drag them into order, though irritatingly, that does nothing, just cosmetic. Alphabetical by email does seem a really bad way to do it, but yes, that appears to be how it works:/

Comment: ah, no - it's not alphabetical - it's first in the list in prefs>accounts... which would be fine if that list were re-orderable, which it's not.